# Moving Messages History from Macbook to iPad Mini

Tags: macbook-pro, ipad, data-synchronization, messages, history

I have my messages synced with my iPad Mini and computer, but I've had the computer longer and I want to copy my message history from my computer over to my iPad. What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

Follow these steps to back up and restore Messages (and other app data) from one iPhone to another:
1. Connect the old iPhone to a power source and turn on Wi-Fi.
2. On the old iPhone - assuming you're running iOS 8 or later - tap Settings > iCloud > Backup. The Backup switch is near the bottom of the large group of controls. (On iOS 7 or earlier, you should tap Settings > iCloud > Storage & Backup.)
3. Make sure iCloud Backup is turned on.

4. Tap Back Up Now, and wait for the backup process to complete. You'll need to remain connected to Wi-Fi for the entirety of this process.
5. Turn on your new iPhone. If you haven't done so already, you'll need to go through the setup process. When asked, tap Restore from iCloud Backup and Next. If you've already been through the setup process, you'll need to reset your iPhone. Tap on Settings > General > Reset and > Erase All Content and Settings.
6. Enter your Apple ID and Password.

Comment: I meant from a computer to iphone, not iphone to iphone. Anything else i can do?